# Pandas: how can I create multi-level columns

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which has the following columns:

```
n_0
n_1
p_0
p_1
e_0
e_1
```

I want to transform it to have columns and sub-columns:

```
0
    n
    p
    e
1
    n
    p
    e
```

I've searched in the documentation, and I'm completely lost on how to implement this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

You can find the example script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=('0_n', '1_n', '0_p', '1_p', 'x'))

indices = set()
groups = set()
others = set()
for c in data.columns:
    if '_' in c:
        (i, g) = c.split('_')
        c2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((i, g),)
        indices.add(int(i))
        groups.add(g)
    else:
        others.add(c)
columns = list(itertools.product(groups, indices))
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
ret = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for c in columns:
    ret[c] = data['%d_%s' % (int(c[1]), c[0])]
for c in others:
    ret[c] = data['%s' % c]
ret.rename(columns={'total': 'total_indices'}, inplace=True)

print("Before:")
print(data)
print("")
print("After:")
print(ret)
```

Sorry for this...

Answer (score 7):

```
columns=[('0', 'n'), ('0', 'p'), ('0', 'e'), ('1', 'n'), ('1', 'p'), ('1', 'e')]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to adjust victor's sort to get OP's specific column format:

```
df = df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```

````
0                                     1
    e           n           p           e           n           p
0   -0.995452   -3.237846   1.298927    -0.269253   -0.857724   -0.461103```
````

Answer (score -2):

There is a simpler solution:

```
  data.columns = data.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

To arrange column names one can also do:

```
 data.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

To change column levels:

```
 data = data.reorder_levels([1,0], axis=1)
```